# Why does my DNS server not update when I switch networks?

Tags: macos, wifi, catalina, dns

When I switch WiFi networks, the DNS setting does not update. So, if the old and new DNS for the WiFi don't match, I have to open network preferences/advanced/DNS and clear the previous entry. That allows the auto-DNS setting from DHCP to come through, but then one gets stuck, and I have to do it again next time.

So, I can fix the issue when it occurs, but it's annoying and sometimes I forget and I lose minutes before I remember why nothing is working. I just don't know why it is stuck. I can't say for certain that it sticks every time since many networks use 192.168.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 or something, and so I might migrate networks and it's fine because it's matching or maybe it's not stuck every time, but it's definitely most of the time and I suspect it's consistent.

I'm just not even sure where to start looking. `resolv.conf` is being auto-generated (though I haven't remembered to check before clearing the previous entry whether this is before or after I clear the stuck entry).

This is a 2019 MacBook Pro 13". Currently on Catalina (10.15.1), though I had the same problem on the previous MacOS version as well.

Comment: It would be helpful to add your macOS version and which Mac Model you have. Just edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Are you using LAN-only resources, i.e. things that do not have public DNS records? An example of this would be web-servers in a lab. If you're not sure, then the answer is no, which means you could simply hardcode `1.1.1.1` and/or `8.8.8.8` for your DNS server and just leave it. Either or both of those DNS servers will work on literally any network that is internet connected.

Comment: No not normally. But, I think I tried that once and the problem was (if I remember this correctly) I was on a network that required DNS resolution through the router to connect you to that "confirmation" page that some wifis make you go through.

Comment: I've started to have the same problem recently. Especially when I open my laptop at a new location, it connects to the local Wifi but keeps the previous DNS settings. Switching Wifi off and on is a quick (but annoying) workaround.